# Want a more standard way for page navigation using Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried a clean and simple way of page navigation using Reactjs.
Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const homepg = "Hi! Welcome to my site.";
const aboutpg = "I am a React Web Developer.";
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { PageCon: "" };
    this.homepg = this.homepg.bind(this);
    this.aboutpg = this.aboutpg.bind(this);
  }
  homepg() {
    this.setState({ PageCon: homepg });
  }
  aboutpg() {
    this.setState({ PageCon: aboutpg });
  }
  render() {
    const { PageCon } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <nav>
          <h1 onClick={this.homepg}>Home</h1>
          <h1 onClick={this.aboutpg}>About</h1>
        </nav>
        <p>{PageCon}</p>{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But I want a more standard method for it. Can you please tell what method you use? Thanks....

Comment: Have you looked at [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a **routing** mechanism.

Take a look at [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router). It's probably the most popular choice for React (for the web).

Here's a very basic example for the use-case you illustrated:

What you're looking for is called a **routing** mechanism.

Take a look at [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router). It's probably the most popular choice for React (for the web).

Here's a very basic example for the use-case you illustrated:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <hr />

          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
);

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
);

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: How can I use it in App.js?

Comment: Maybe the functional component I used confused you. I just updated the example with **App** component, like the one in your question. Does this answers your question?